Messages Not Emitting from Current Device in Real-Time Chat
Frontend: Flutter (using socket_io_client ^3.0.0)
Backend: Node.js (using socket.io ^4.8.0)
I'm implementing real-time messaging in chat rooms.
When I send a message from my device, it gets stored in the database, but the socket doesn't pick it up. However, when another user sends a message, my device is able to receive it in real-time.
What could be causing this issue?
Messages Not Emitting from Current Device in Real-Time Chat
